# How to add paragraphs, images to an android application?

Tags: android, menu, onclick, displaytag

I am creating a simple application for a college. I have added menu items. Now I want to add paragraphs, images to as a new page content on menu click. I have created an intent for the menu item. Now further what to do?

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Comment: @sinceksaji, I have worked till the last step of the above tutorial. Now for example, when I click Bookmark menu as per the above tutorial, I am getting a message as "Bookmark is selected". But i want to display a page of content having paragraphs and images. How can i do this? Please guide me.

Comment: @sinceksaji, when I create a new android project, two xml files are created in res/layout folder. For example as per the above tutorial when I  Create a new project File -> Android Project. While creating a new project give activity name as FirstScreenActivity, I am getting activity_main.xml, fragment_main.xml, firstscreenactivity.xml, fragment_firstscreenactivity.xml. Y so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intent to pass to the next activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Yourclass.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/